# Table appearing in front of my dropdown menu

Tags: javascript, html, css, highcharts

I have a table on a pie chart. The `Highcharts` `export` button is directly above it. When I click on the menu, it gets hidden behind the table. The table needs to have a `z-index` of `1000` in order to appear on the chart at all, but I need the export dropdown menu to overwrite this.

How do I get the dropdown menu to override the table that has a `z-index: 1000`?
[image]

**Table**

```
<table style="background-color: white; position:absolute; z-index: 1000; margin-left: 550px; margin-top:50px;  width:20%; font-size: 12px;">
 <th>Output (MW)</th>
 <tr></tr>
  <tr>
    <td><strong>Total</strong></td>
    <td id="total" align="right"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><strong>Renewables</strong></td>
    <td id="renew" align="right"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Worth your while looking at the z-index of the other components so that you can change the 1000 and make room for the overlay

Comment: can you make a jsfiddle of this like you did in the other question?

Answer (score 2):

highcharts-contextmenu is the class of export options , you need to use following css

```
.highcharts-container {
position: inherit !important;
}
.highcharts-contextmenu  {
 z-index:9999!important;
}
```

See [Updated fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/Nishith/2uf8e3xu/5/)

Answer (score 0):

Decrease `z-index`value for you table until goes behind menu. If table still needs `z-index:1000` to appear in chart then add `z-index:1001` for `Highcharts export` menu's class in your CSS file.